# Add (media) files to a file of custom format in C++

Tags: c++, file, encryption, format, sdl

I made a game in C++, however I've noticed that most video games add all the media files they use (sprite sheets, XML tables, mp3) inside a file of custom format to avoid being tampered.
I don't want to insert them inside the executable, I just want the executable to look for them inside a file of custom format.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's just like creating and saving any other file, but you add your own extension at the end of it. Are you doing this just to avoid tampering? Saving things under a different file extension does very little to prevent tampering. I think what you are looking for is encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Try using any of the BSD-Licensed (NiH's libzip, for example) zip libraries, fast and easy containers for your program, integrity-checked and optionally encrypted.

Anoter option:
SDL allows loading from memory and other custom resources using the SDL_*RWops functions, check http://www.kekkai.org/roger/sdl/rwops/rwops.html. It wouldn't be hard to read files from an uncompressed container (zip, tar, romfs) using RWops.